How to add two pandas dataframe in a way that achieve the desired behaviour described below
the resulting dataframe will sum the value of matching index, but if an index is missing in one dataframe but present in the other, it will just carry them over instead of removing them.
for example
df1 = 
        data
index1  4.2
index2  5.0
index3  3.0

df2 = 
        data
index2  1.0
index3  7.0
index4  2.0

result = 
        data
index1  4.2 ( carry from df1)
index2  6.0 (5.0 + 1.0)
index3  10.0 (3.0 + 7.0)
index4  2.0 ( carry from df2)

I tried using + and add(), also concatenate, they either remove the index or fill it with na if the index is missing from one of the dataframe

You can try pd.concat and sum along rows:
out = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1).sum(axis=1).to_frame(name="data")
print(out)

Prints:
        data
index1   4.2
index2   6.0
index3  10.0
index4   2.0


OR: using .merge:
out = (
    df1.merge(df2, left_index=True, right_index=True, how="outer")
    .sum(axis=1)
    .to_frame(name="data")
)
print(out)


you can try
import pandas as pd

# Create the dataframes
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'data': [4.2, 5.0, 3.0]}, index=['index1', 'index2', 'index3'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'data': [1.0, 7.0, 2.0]}, index=['index2', 'index3', 'index4'])

# Perform addition with fill_value=0 to handle missing indices
result = df1.add(df2, fill_value=0)

print(result)

Output:
        data
index1    4.2
index2    6.0
index3   10.0
index4    2.0


import pandas as pd

# Sample dataframes DF1 and DF2

    data1 = {'A': [1, 2, 3, 4], 'B': [0.5, 1.0, 1.5, 2.0]}
    data2 = {'A': [2, 3, 4, 5], 'B': [1.0, 1.5, 2.0, 2.5]}

    DF1 = pd.DataFrame(data1)
    print("DF1")
    print(DF1)
    DF2 = pd.DataFrame(data2)
    print("DF2")
    print(DF2)

# Merge DF1 and DF2 on column A, keeping all indices from both dataframes

    merged = pd.merge(DF1, DF2, on='A', how='outer', suffixes=('_DF1', '_DF2'))

# Function to combine values from columns B based on the merge result

    def combine_values(row):
        if not pd.isnull(row['B_DF1']) and not pd.isnull(row['B_DF2']):
            return row['B_DF1'] + row['B_DF2']
        elif not pd.isnull(row['B_DF1']):
            return row['B_DF1']
        else:
            return row['B_DF2']

# Apply the function to create column B in the new dataframe

    merged['B'] = merged.apply(combine_values, axis=1)

# Select only columns A and B from the merged dataframe to create DF3

    DF3 = merged[['A', 'B']]

    print("DF3")
    print(DF3)

